# Why do I get an error like this when I go to npm run build? Module not found: Can't resolve

Tags: reactjs, npm-start

Why do I get an error like this when I go to npm run build?
There is no such thing as before. But now this one is coming.

> build
> next build

info  - Skipping linting
info  - Checking validity of types
info  - Disabled SWC as replacement for Babel because of custom Babel configuration ".babelrc" https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/swc-disabled
info  - Using external babel configuration from C:\Users\pasindu\Downloads\react-personal-site-master\react-personal-site-master\portfolio.babelrc
info  - Creating an optimized production build
Failed to compile.

./src/pages/homepage/home.jsx
Module not found: Can't resolve '../../components/Services5/services5' in 'C:\Users\name\Downloads\react-personal-site-master\react-personal-site-master\portfolio\src\pages\homepage'

./src/pages/homepage/home.jsx
Module not found: Can't resolve '../../components/About-us5/about-us5' in 'C:\Users\name\Downloads\react-personal-site-master\react-personal-site-master\portfolio\src\pages\homepage'

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.